# WPF Custom Control Click and Drag / Follow Mouse Pointer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, drag-and-drop

I have read various solutions to the problem and I now wonder which one is to be preferred in which situation (and mine especially)

I have created a Custom Control that Renders a Color wheel and a circle (`Ellipse`) on a canvas in the middle. I now want to be able to click and drag that circle as a selector on the color wheel.

Possible solutions include: Overriding the `OnClick` and / or `OnMouseMove` events and update the circles position by either dependency properties or using TemplateParts or even generating the circle in the Controls Code Behind.

I wonder if it would also be possible to use triggers in XAML to achieve this effect and which solution would deliver the "smoothest" motion.

Update 1: To address comments, here is some code:

ColorPicker.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TrigDebugUtil.Controls">


    <Style x:Key="ColorPicker" TargetType="{x:Type local:ColorPicker}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ColorPicker}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Image Source="{TemplateBinding ColorWheelImage}" Width="500" Height="500"/>
                            <Canvas Width="10" Height="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Property=SelectedColor}" Width="10" Height="10" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness=".5" />
                            </Canvas>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

ColorPicker.cs

```
namespace TrigDebugUtil.Controls
{
    public class ColorPicker : Control
    {
        #region Private Fields

        #endregion //Private Fields

        #region Dependency Properties
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorWheelImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ColorWheelImage", typeof(WriteableBitmap), typeof(ColorPicker));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedColor", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(ColorPicker));
        #endregion //Dependency Properties

        #region Properties
        public WriteableBitmap ColorWheelImage
        {
            get { return (WriteableBitmap)GetValue(ColorWheelImageProperty); }
            private set { SetValue(ColorWheelImageProperty, value);  }
        }

        public SolidColorBrush SelectedColor
        {
            get { return (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(SelectedColorProperty); }
            private set { SetValue(SelectedColorProperty, value); }
        }
        #endregion //Properties

        static ColorPicker()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ColorPicker), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ColorPicker)));
        }

        public ColorPicker()
        {
            ColorWheelImage = new WriteableBitmap(500, 500, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Rgb24, null);
            SelectedColor = Brushes.White;
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            Byte[] pixels = new Byte[1500 * 500];

            // Update algo here


            ColorWheelImage.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, 500, 500), pixels, 1500, 0);

        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to click on the ellipse in the canvas and move it to another location in the control itself (i.e. on the image)

Comment: I'd remove your "side question" from this one and create it as a new question in it's own right (assuming it hasn't been asked already that is).

Comment: Binding Targets have to be DependencyProperties a Binding Source can be a number of different things including DependencyProperties , CLR properties and resources.

Comment: could you describe how the color will is built and what it does

Comment: @eranotzap I have added additional code to explain the problem

Answer (score 0):

For people having the same issue, one possible solution is to implement the draggable object as a `Thumb` and overriding its `DragStarted` `DragDelta` and `DragCompleted` events.

Here's an example:

```
    private void OnThumbDragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        Thumb thumb = sender as Thumb;

        double newX = Canvas.GetLeft(thumb) + e.HorizontalChange;
        double newY = Canvas.GetTop(thumb) + e.VerticalChange;

            Canvas.SetLeft(thumb, newX);
            Canvas.SetTop(thumb, newY);



        // This is optional for routed events.
        e.RoutedEvent = ThumbDragDeltaEvent;
        RaiseEvent(e);
    }
```

without using  the `DragStarted` and `DragCompleted` Events.

I'd like to see comments on wether this is a preferred solution or if it has any disadvantages. From what I can see it's not the most efficient, on fast mouse movements, the thumb movement is delayed and not always "right under the mouse"